# how to add autocompelete search bar in nativescript pure javascript

Tags: javascript, search, autocomplete, nativescript

i am trying to add an autocomplete search bar in nativescript project using pure JavaScript, there are a lot of tutorials to do it in typescript , and when i tried to convert the code to JavaScript i received errors , i am using nativescript 3.3.0, i cant find a demo for javascript , any help ?

this is main-view-model.js:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;

function RegisterViewModel() {
    var viewModel = new Observable();
    viewModel.shows = [
        {
        name: "Default Mail Client" ,
        info:"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command - Under command, enter the full path to the email client then %1  c:\internet\Netscape\program\netscape.exe %1 c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe %1",
        },

        {
        name: "test head2" ,
        info:"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FaultLogFile "
        },
        {
            name: "test head2" ,
            info:"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FaultLogFile "
            },

    ];

    viewModel.cmd = [
        {
        name: "CMD Title1" ,
        info:"Cmd Details1"
        },
        {
            name: "Generate Program Fault Log" ,
            info:"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\FaultLogFile "
            },

    ];


    return viewModel;
}
exports.RegisterViewModel = RegisterViewModel;
```

main-page.js:

```
var RegisterViewModel = require("./main-view-model").RegisterViewModel;
var frameModule = require('ui/frame');

var viewModel = new RegisterViewModel();

exports.getInfo = function (args) {

    var info = args.view.bindingContext;
    console.log(info); // [Object object]
    console.log(info["info"]); // e.g. info["name"] === "Reg4"
    // info is Object of type { name: "Reg4" }

    var navigationEntry = {
        moduleName: "RegisterDetails",
        context: { name: info["info"] }
    }
    frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
}


exports.getInfoCmd = function (args) {

        var info = args.view.bindingContext;
        console.log(info); // [Object object]
        console.log(info["info"]);

        var navigationEntry = {
            moduleName: "CmdDetails",
            context: { name: info["info"] }
        }
        frameModule.topmost().navigate(navigationEntry);
    }

exports.loaded = function (args) {
    args.object.bindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

and this is main-page.xml :

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"  navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" loaded="loaded">

    <StackLayout class="p-20">
        <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="Search" text="" clear="onClear" submit="onSubmit" submit="{{search}}"/>
         <!--<SearchBar  visibility="{{loggedIn ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}" class="search-bar"></SearchBar>-->
        <TabView >
            <TabView.items >
                <TabViewItem title="register"   >
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                       <!--<TextField text="{{ filter }}" hint="Enter filter"/> 1 -->

                        <ListView items="{{ shows }}" itemTap="getInfo" class="ListView">
                            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                                <Label text="{{ name }}"  />
                            </ListView.itemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>

                <TabViewItem title="CMD" class="TabView">
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                        <ListView items="{{ cmd }}" itemTap="getInfoCmd" class="ListView">
                            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                                <Label text="{{ name }}" />
                            </ListView.itemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>
                 <TabViewItem title="G.Policy" class="TabView">
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                        <ListView items="{{ cmd }}" itemTap="getInfoCmd" class="ListView">
                            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                                <Label text="{{ name }}" />
                            </ListView.itemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>

                 <TabViewItem title="Services" class="TabView">
                    <TabViewItem.view>
                        <ListView items="{{ cmd }}" itemTap="getInfoCmd" class="ListView">
                            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                                <Label text="{{ name }}" />
                            </ListView.itemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </TabViewItem.view>
                </TabViewItem>
            </TabView.items>

        </TabView>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? The pasted code does not seem to have anything to do with autocompletion.

Comment: Just I want to know how make a filter data or search

Comment: Well, did you look anywhere on the internet for a plugin that does that already? - https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-autocomplete

Comment: Yes, but the plugin use typescript not JavaScript, and when I tried to convert the code to JavaScript I received errors, if there is a simple way to filter data, it's will be good

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, which after compilation becomes JavaScript. A plugin written in TypeScript is essentially a JavaScript plugin. Just copy-paste from the demo, or play the demo and let the transpiler do its job, then copy-paste from the transpiled javascript files. TypeScript == JavaScript.